# Simple question about the the holographic principle and the uncertainty principle

Tags: heisenberg-uncertainty-principle, holographic-principle

Given: The holographic principle as proposed by Susskind that states that the maximum amount of information stored in a 3D volume can be dictated by its surface area.
Would not: The simple square-cubed law of geometry indicate that the number of Plank scale volume elements needed to discretize the volume would exceed the number of Plank size area elements on the surface. Therefore, information on the surface would need to be resolved at sub plank scale.

In other words my question is how do you resolve the holographic principle and the uncertainty principle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Interesting question. I can only give a qualitative answer that motivates the problem and basically restates the theory that surface area imposes a hard limit on information storage. But it’s ~probably worthwhile to do so. I’ll follow this and see if another answer provides more intuition or detail about the specifics of that:

One way to look at the Holographic Principle is that it proves we cannot do what you’re describing. Or, alternatively, that the minimum bit size that can be achieved has a hard limit determined by the surface area.

Because we are talking about information, the retrieval process must be included. There is clearly some other limit being hit when it comes to information. If there is a $2\hslash$ wide “bit” deep inside our cube, we cannot read that - cannot shoot a photon at it for example. I guess we’d start at the outer layer of bits and read those and somehow get rid of them. Then the next layer. Meanwhile there are quantum realities and uncertainty principle governing what can be achieved. When the holographic principle accounts for our interacting in an ideal way, he has shown that we still hit a hard limit with that retrieval process.

Comment: I added a note is interesting question which I appear to be the only one who thinks so